# Cant login after installation

Tags: system-installation, password, login-screen

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 but then i try to login using my password the screen goes black and some text is shown realy fast in the upper left corner then I am back at the login. Why cant I login?

Comment: Press CTRL+ALT+F1, and log in. Then run "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade". If there is an error, post it, if not, reboot.

Comment: Did it but its still the same. I try to login and end up back at the login page. I get a box for a sec telling me there is a problem with the system.

Comment: Please look for errors within /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log

Comment: ok.... and how do i do that. do I type it after doing Ctrl-Alt-F1

Comment: Please get familiar with the bash, you want to read a log (text) file, so look how to do it.

Comment: I typed it and got access denied

Comment: how do I learn more about bash. I dont know what that is.

Comment: Maybe a search engine might tell you that.

Comment: sorry to waste your time. I thought this was a place to get help with Ubuntu problems. I guess I was wrong. Be well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am also here to help, but if we have to explain things that you can find online easy, it's not the way it's meant to be.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)

Comment: its easy then you know what to looks for and i thought that was what i was doing here. finding answers online. Everything is easy for someone who knows how to do it.